# Magento Model override

Tags: magento, model, overriding

Trying to extend a model for a custom extension. Simple enough...but rewrite doesnt seem to be working.

i want to rewrite the following model, located in a module in the community code folder:

**Belvg_Stores_Model_State**

With my own, located in a module in the local code folder:

**Myco_Storelocator_Model_State**

Here is the config xml from Myco_Storelocator. The block rewrite is working...the state rewrite is not.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>

<global>
    <modules>
        <myco_storelocator>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </myco_storelocator>
    </modules>
    <blocks>
        <storelocator><class>Myco_Storelocator_Block</class></storelocator>
        <stores>
            <rewrite>
                    <front>Myco_Storelocator_Block_Front</front>
            </rewrite>
        </stores>
    </blocks>
    <models>
        <stores>
            <rewrite>
                <state>Myco_Storelocator_Model_State</state>
            </rewrite>
        </stores>
    </models>
</global>   
<frontend>
  <layout>   
        <updates>   
            <storelocator>   
                <file>storelocator.xml</file>   
            </storelocator>   
        </updates>   
    </layout>
</frontend>   
</config>
```

Thanks for the help...

Comment: are you extending `Belvg_Stores_Model_State` in your `Myco_Storelocator_Model_State` class? Also you may try a different unique node instead of `state`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to add the following to the relevant model rewrite...same as the block rewrite section:

```
<storelocator><class>Myco_Storelocator_Model</class></storelocator>
```

...doh.